# How to Hide Last Three li form ul?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide first two li from ul I am using like

```
  <ul class="newade">
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li>sub1</li>
       <li>sub2</li>
       <li>sub3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

But When I am trying to hide using JQUERY I am facing a problem it is including sub-list also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.newade').find("li:gt(1)").hide();
</script>
```

But I want result like this

```
<ul class="newade">
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li>sub1</li>
       <li>sub2</li>
       <li>sub3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li style="display:none;">Three</li>
   <li style="display: none;">Four</li>
   <li style="display: none;">Five</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: The HTML is invalid, as [`<UL>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul) can only have `<Li>` as child. First __correct__ your HTML

Comment: @Satpal that's wrong, there is no such a rule in html https://jsfiddle.net/hy0adev4/1/

Comment: @user3003238 Yes there is. See the specification: https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html-markup-20120329/ul.html **_"Permitted contents Zero or more li elements"_**

Comment: @user3003238 validate that - it will be invalid:  *Element ul not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)*.  Just because you can do it, doesn't make it valid

Comment: Just use this: **$('.newade > li:not(:lt(2))').hide();**

Answer (score 2):

Use this line : **$('.newade > li:not(:lt(2))').hide();**

```js
$('.newade > li:not(:lt(2))').hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="newade">
            <li>
                <ul>
                    <li>sub1</li>
                    <li>sub2</li>
                    <li>sub3</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
            <li>Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
        </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Why script when css can do it? :)

```
.newade>li:nth-child(1), .newade>li:nth-child(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

```css
.newade>li:nth-child(1), .newade>li:nth-child(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="newade">
   <li>
     <ul>
       <li>sub1</li>
       <li>sub2</li>
       <li>sub3</li>
     </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   <li>Four</li>
   <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
.newade>li:nth-child(1), .newade>li:nth-child(2) {
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: I have a dynamic value it is just a demo

Answer (score -1):

Use css [nth selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anth-child) where n is 0,1,2.... so in first case it will be -0+2 , in second case it will be -1+2 and

```css
.newade li:nth-child(-n+2) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="newade">
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>sub1</li>
      <li>sub2</li>
      <li>sub3</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
</ul>
```